# How to delete the whole row when it starts with 'H' in a comma separarted csv file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, regular-expression

How to delete the whole row when it starts with 'H' in a comma separated csv file  for below example,

```
H,NYR,257,10,11,000, TESTING,055,000,2023-05-10
D,NYR,257,10,11,000, TESTING,055,000,2023-05-10
H,NYR,257,10,11,000, TESTING,055,000,2023-05-10
F,NYR,257,10,11,000, TESTING,055,000,2023-05-10
H,NYR,257,10,11,000, TESTING,055,000,2023-05-10
D,NYR,257,10,11,000, TESTING,055,000,2023-05-10
H,NYR,257,10,11,000, TESTING,055,000,2023-05-10
D,NYR,257,10,11,000, TESTING,055,000,2023-05-10
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. When asking questions about text processing, please be sure to add a minimal reproducible example of the problem - i.e. (possible anonymized) example input, desired output, what you already tried, and in which way the output you got from your attempts deviates from the expectation. That way you can avoid receiving answers that you already know won't work, and contributors can verify proposed solutions before posting them as answers.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't need `sed` or `awk`. It's trivially done with `grep -v '^H'` and redirect the output to another file or pipe it into another program as needed.

You could use `sed -i` or `grep` & `sponge` if you need an in-place edit of the file.  e.g.

```
sed -i -n '/^H/!p' file.csv
```

or

```
sed -i '/^H/d' file.csv
```

or

```
grep -v '^H' file.csv | sponge file.csv
```

Personally, I generally don't use in-place editing, I prefer to use a separate file because disk space is abundant and cheap, but information can't be recovered once it has been deleted.

---

If you need to process the entire file with `awk` anyway, just add a rule like the following at the top of your script:

```
/^H/ { next };
```

This will skip all lines beginning with "H".  All other lines will be processed as usual by subsequent awk rules.

Similarly, you could use `next if /^H/;` in a perl script to skip lines beginning with "H".